# Java netbeans binding. how to refresh bindings..?

Tags: java, netbeans, binding, jlabel

i have a jlabel and using netbeans i have bound it to a property on the form.

the problem is how do i refresh the binding values when the property that the label text has been bound to has changed.
this.firePropertyChange works but smells bad... i would like someonething like this.bindingGroup.refresh or this.refresh that will update the labels text

for example
the jLabel.text is bound to form someValue

```
private someClass someThing;
public String getSomeValue(){
  return someThing.getSomeThing();
}
//when someMethof is fired the jlabel should update its text value
public void someMethod(){
  someThing = someThingElse;
  bindingGroup.refresh()?????

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately if you want to use the Beans Binding API, you'll have to deal with the smell of `firePropertyChange`.

However, I don't see what the problem is? It's quite a simple change.  Change your class to the following:

```
private someClass someThing;
public String getSomeValue(){
  return someThing.getSomeThing();
}
//when someMethof is fired the jlabel should update its text value
public void someMethod(){
  someClass oldValue = someThing;
  someThing = someThingElse;
  this.firePropertyChange("someValue", oldValue, someThing);

}
```

Check out [this article on java.net for more details](http://today.java.net/article/2008/03/18/synchronizing-properties-beans-binding-jsr-295).

Comment: the thing i have found with the fireprop... is that old val and new val are ignored. which is not a bad thing. if there a way to find out the names of the properties that are changed at run time that way i could call my bind() method that will automatically do all that for me.

Comment: i found that if you call firePropertyChange on the main container with three null args it would cause all bindings to be refreshed. cheers! :D